# Spring boot BlazeDS easy integration

Tags: java, spring, apache-flex, annotations, blazeds

Im creating a flex app with spring boot server project, in my server java i doesnt have any xml configuration file and i need to integrate blazeds for communication. I read a lots of guides ,but all are with xml configurations, there a way to integrate blazeds with only spring annotations?
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

No there is not, your flex application needs the BlazeDS XML configuration at compile time in order to be aware of the services.